# Как сделать переключатель скрыть показать на Vue js

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

У меня есть такой код, он выводит посты, мне нужно сделать при клике на кнопку Удалить окошко с вопросом Вы Уверенны?
Но дело в том что когда я нажимаю на удалить, эти окошки отображаються во всех постах

```
<div class="post" v-for="(record, idx) of records" :key="record.id">
                <span>{{record.date}}</span>
                <h4>{{record.headline}}</h4>
                <p>{{record.posttext}}</p>
                <div class="post_control">
                    <button class="btn btn-edit" @click="modal">Редактировать</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-remove" @click="isHidden = false">Удалить</button>
                    <!-- Subject -->
                    <div class="controlSubject" v-if="!isHidden">
                        <div class="modalTitle">
                            Вы уверены?
                        </div>
                        <button @click="remove(idx)">Да</button>
                        <button @click="isHidden = !isHidden">Нет</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- / Subject -->
                </div>
            </div>

    data: () => ({
                isHidden: true,

            }),
```

Comment: Я думал по поводу этого, но так не пойдет, нужно для каждого итема сделать

Comment: Дело в том что это мой первый опыт с Vue js и разрабатываю я сейчас используя Vue cli, если вы можете дать ответ просто без vue cli я думаю будет хорошо, но смогу ли я это применить в своем проекте?

Comment: Я вас понял, вы ее убрали из вопроса, так как это на вью сделать без CLI ?

Answer (score 0):

Серфил по тому что возвращаеться из поста получилось

```
<template>
    <!-- Posts -->
    <div class="posts">
        <div class="post" v-for="(record, idx) of records" :key="record.id">
            <span>{{record.date}}</span>
            <h4>{{record.headline}}</h4>
            <p>{{record.posttext}}</p>
            <div class="post_control">
                <button class="btn btn-edit">Редактировать</button>
                <button class="btn btn-remove" @click="removeQuestion">
                    Удалить запись
                </button>
                <!-- Subject -->
                <div class="controlSubject h">
                    <div class="modalTitle">
                        Вы уверены?
                    </div>
                    <button @click="remove(idx)">Да</button>
                    <button @click="removeCancel">Нет</button>
                </div>
                <!-- / Subject -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- / Posts -->
</template>


<script>
    import firebase from 'firebase/app'
    export default {
        name: "PostsEdit",
        data: () => ({
            records: []
        }),
        methods: {
            removeQuestion: function(record) {
                let windowControl = record.path[1].children[2];
                windowControl.classList.remove('h');
                console.log(windowControl);
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```